# Frequently updating a large JSON file on Amazon S3 and potential write conflict

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb

I first want to give a little overview on what I'm trying to tackle. My service is frequently fetching posts from various sources such as Instagram, Twitter, etc. and I want to store the posts in one large JSON file on S3. The file name would be something like: `{slideshowId}_feed.json`

My website will display the posts in a slideshow, and the slideshow will simply poll the S3 file every minute or so to get the latest data. It might even poll another file such as `{slideshowId}_meta.json` that has timestamp from when the large file changed in order to save bandwidth.

The reason I want to keep the posts in a single JSON file is mainly to save cost. I could have each source as its own file, e.g. `{slideshowId}_twitter.json`, `{slideshowId}_instagram.json`, etc. but then the slideshow would need to send GET request to every source every minute, thus increasing the cost. We're talking about thousands of slideshows running at once, so the cost needs to scale well.

---

Now back to the question. There may be more than one instance of the service running that checks Instagram and other sources for new posts, depending on how much I need to scale out. The problem with that is the risk of one service overwriting the S3 file while another one might 
already be writing to it.

Each service that needs to save posts to the JSON file would first have to GET the file, process it and check that the new posts are not duplicated in the JSON file, and then store the new or updated posts.

---

1. Could I have each service write the data to some queue like the Simple Queue Service
   (SQS) and then have some worker that takes care of writing the posts to the S3 file?
2. I thought about using AWS Kinesis, but it just processes the data
   from the sources and dumps it to S3. I need to process what has been
   written to the large JSON file as well to do some book keeping.
3. I had an idea of using DynamoDB to store the posts (basically to do the book keeping), and
   then I would simply have the service query all the data needed for a
   single slideshow from DynamoDB and store it to S3. That way the services would simply send the posts to DynamoDB.

There must be some clever way to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use s3.  Why are you copying a file into s3 and then out from s3 to your website?  Why not make the file dynamically from a database and use local caching?  Just seems an odd design, I don't see what s3 adds to it

Comment: if you insist on having a big structured file on S3 at all times, then your best bet for updating it is to require instances of your service to acquire a write lock before updating the file. if you are open to suggestions about the whole architecture, there might be a better design to solve your problem.

Comment: @Vorsprung That's pretty much the strategy I have today, but my problem is that I have over 50 million requests per month poking my API for data. The API has great cache mechanism but I'm also running out of connections, thus I need to scale out the API and increase the cost of my infrastructure exponentially.

The S3 method would put the load on Amazon and decrease the cost significantly ($0.004 per 10,000 requests). It would also remove the dependency on my API.

Comment: @grepe I'm definitely open to suggestions about the whole architecture! :) Whatever scales well and saves cost!

Comment: ok, two questions: how big is the file that stores your data and do you need to process the whole file at once (e.g. update different parts of structure when a new chunk of data comes in)?

Comment: A typical slideshow has around 300 posts on average, but it can be up to 10,000 posts. The file can also be gzipped, meaning the file size would be at most few MBs. The file could have section for each source (instagram, twitter, etc.) so the whole file wouldn't need to be processed. The main reason I need to process it is to avoid duplicated posts.
Each post can have 0...100 comments, text, and a reference to ext. image or video.

Comment: I don't quite follow how "I need to scale out the API and increase the cost of my infrastructure exponentially. The S3 method would put the load on Amazon" is your 'API' getting a large json document, and that's it?  It's not clear to me how external users and your own site and this proposed s3 file interact with each other.

Comment: @Vorsprung Slideshows pokes my API for new data from each feed provider. The data returned is usually the latest 50 posts. The slideshow then does the book keeping of checking if those posts have already been added to the slideshow or not. If not, the slideshow will poke the API for the next 50 posts using pagination.

The problem is this: Lets say that one of my users puts a slideshow in an iframe on a very popular website. I get traffic from e.g. 10,000 users asking for new data. The API can barely handle the requests.
Now imagine if those 10,000 users would poke the S3 file, no load.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for your use case

- there are many users for a single large s3 file
- the file is updated often
- the file path (ideally) should be consistent to make it easier to get and cache
- the s3 file is generated by a process on a ec2 and updated once per minute

If the GET rate is less than 800 per second then AWS is happy with it.  If not then you'll have to talk to them and maybe find another way.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

The file updates will be atomic so there are no issues with locking etc.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html
Presumably if a user requests "during" an update they will see the old version.  This behaviour is transparent to both parties

File updates are "eventually" consistent.  As you want to keep the url the same you will be updating the same object path in s3.

If you are serving across regions then the time it takes to become consistent might be an issue.  For the same region it seems to take a few seconds.  AWS don't seem to be very open about this, so it's probably best to test it for your use case.  As your file is small and the updates are per 60 seconds then I would imagine it would be ok.  You might have to assume in your API description that updates actually happen over a greater time than 60 seconds to take this into account

As ec2 and s3 run on different parts of the AWS infrastructure (ec2 in a VPC and s3 behind a public https)  You will pay for transfer costs from ec2 to s3

I would imagine that you will be serving the s3 file via the s3 "pretend to be a website" feature.  You will have to configure this too, but that is trivial

Comment: Please note that the service running on EC2 will be asynchronous. Lets say it's fetching 200 posts from Twitter, and Twitter only gives you 50 posts at once. So my service will make 4 async calls to Twitter. There's no guarantee on which request will finish first. The problem here is that two requests might finish roughly at the same time. 
The first request fetches the S3 file and adds the posts
The second request does the same
The first request writes the changes
The second request writes the changes
Here the second request will overwrite the changes from the first request.

Comment: No.  Keep your cannonical data on the host doing the fetch from twitter.  When itis is updated, flush it to s3.  Never pull the s3 back to the ec2 running the twitter scanner.  Always write, never read.  The s3 copy is only used for reads from users

Comment: But how would I avoid duplicated data, e.g. two responses from Twitter might include the same post. (That's why I need some book keeping). Unless of course the client-side handles that. So you would basically every minute have the EC2 service fetch all the posts from Twitter? This is where API rate limit could cause a big issue for me (especially on Instagram, 5000 per hour or 83 per minute). I might also have to do additional requests to get the post comments, reference to high resolution video, etc. So I might easily run out of calls quickly.

Comment: I don't think that s3 can solve the problem of your limited access to the twitter or Instagram API.  You said "I have 50 million requests a month poking my API" you didn't say "I am getting rate limited by Instagram" :).  You can move the traffic incoming to you onto s3.   s3 will do nothing for your requests to these external APIs

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

[image]

- The Kinesis stream would need to have enough capacity to handle writes from all your feed producers. For about 25/month you get to do 2000 writes per second.
- Lambda would be simply fired whenever there is enough new items on your stream. You can configure trigger to wait for 1000 new items and then run the Lambda to read all new items from the stream, process them and write them to REDIS (ElastiCache). Your bill for that should be well under 10/month.
- Smart key selection would take care of duplicate items. You can also set the items to expire if you need to. According to your description your items should definitely fit into memory and you can add instances if you need more capacity for reading and/or reliability. Running two REDIS instances with enough memory to handle your data would cost around 26/month.
- Your service would use REDIS instead of S3, so you would only pay for the data transfer and only if your service is not on AWS (<10/month?).

Comment: So let's say someone puts the slideshow in an iframe on a very popular website where there are 10,000 concurrent users. All of them send the request straight to the Redis cluster? How would you feed the users the posts?

Comment: hmmm... maybe i misunderstood the question then. i thought that was the part you had figured out already and i was just suggesting to replace the S3 with REDIS for your existing infrastructure, but you wanted to use S3 as distribution system. then by all means - just run something that will read the results from REDIS and write it to S3 (then you should not need the lock).